# How to determine if an acquittal should not have happened?

Tags: united-states, law, judiciary

A lot of people are saying that George Zimmerman should not have been acquitted over charges relating to his shooting of Trayvon Martin.

As far as I'm aware, people are arguing that Zimmerman was guilty of the charges against him, and if the verdict wasn't guilty, then it must be because the trial system went wrong.

Are there any other metrics for evaluating whether the trial functioned as it ought to, such as how much attention the jury gave to the case, or how long they discussed the case?

Comment: Hardly anybody is arguing that under the current law a guilty verdict was the correct verdict - especially given that a jury is required to return a not guilty verdict in case of 'reasonable doubt'. The arguments are whether the law and system that resulted in this verdict are 'just'.

Comment: "metrics for evaluating whether the trial functioned as it ought to" = the only reliable metric I know if is how well the case does in the appellate courts (if it is appealed).

Comment: I think this is a reasonable and answerable question.  Political Claim = "Zimmerman should have been convicted"  Question "What criteria would have sufficed in this instance?"

Comment: @DJClayworth I've seen people on my twitter feed saying that the verdict is wrong. They haven't been citing in depth analyses backing up their position, though.

Comment: @AffableGeek Even if "Zimmermann should have been convicted" is a political claim, I still don't think there is an actual question here. If it's a political question then the answer to "how do we determine..." is "according to whatever political philosphy you adhere to". Politically this is no more a sensible question than "how do we decide what the right rate of income tax is". It will be entirely open for discussion.

Comment: And let me point out that the only answer we have so far treats it purely from a legal point of view, which is off topic.

Comment: @Mods I flagged this as off-topic, yet when I visit my profile page I don't see any flags pending, how come?

Comment: @DJClayworth Law and politics are coupled.

Comment: 'Coupled' does not mean 'the same'. There are many aspects of the law that are nothing to do with politics. Legal processes are not to do with politics. Questions about what is legal are not to do with politidcs. Politics plays its part in forming laws, but it isn't - or shouldn't be - part of implementing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a legal standpoint the deciding of whether or not the trial functioned as it  ought to is called an appeal

and an acquittal can't be appealed because of the Double-Jeopardy clause in the 5th amendment of the US Constitution.